# Getting error while installing the great exepectation tool in local

Tags: python, pip, great-expectations

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\dineshreddy.d\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\jedi\\third_party\\django-stubs\\django-stubs\\contrib\\contenttypes\\management\\commands\\remove_stale_contenttypes.pyi'
```

I am unable to install the great expecatation packages in the local . Getting the above error.

I tried with the `pip install great_expectations --user`  command but i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running into an issue with a missing file when trying to install the greatexpectations package. The file that is missing is located in the

```
C:Usersdineshreddy.dAppDataLocalPackagesPythonSoftwareFoundation contains the file that is missing. The removeestale_contenttypes.pyi file can be found in the Python.3.10qbz5n2kfra8p0LocalCachelocal-packagesPython310site-packagesjedithirdpartydjango-stubsdjango-stubscontribcontenttypesmanagementcommands directory.
```

You can try reinstalling the jedi package with the pip install jedi command to resolve this issue. You can also try installing the great expectations package in a virtual environment to avoid conflicts with other packages.

Comment: getting the same issue while reinstalling the jedi

Comment: you will need to find the missing file and install it into the specified directory. You may be able to find the file online or you may need to contact the  support team for assistance